# How to assign value to a variable only if value meets a condition?

Tags: c

I am a first year college student working on a project for my beginner programming class. I am trying to ask the user for a value, which represents the starting amount, which must be greater than or equal to zero. As I am debugging my program, I noticed that when I input a negative value, the program asks me to re-enter a value that is greater than or equal to zero (like it should), however the initial negative value gets assigned to the variable to do the computations, resulting in an incorrect output. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to how I could assign the positive value to the variable.

I have a function that asks the user to input a value, stores this value in a variable, and then returns the variable to the main function. In my main function, I have a variable set equal to the function call. After this initialization, I have tried using while loops and if statements to check whether or not the value is less than zero, and if it is, tell the user that the input should be greater than or equal to zero, and call the function again.

```
int main(){
   int initialSize = getInitialSize();

   if (initialSize < 0) {
      printf("Initial size must be greater than or equal to 0");
      getInitialSize();
   }
}

int getInitialSize() {
   int startingAmount;
   printf("Enter initial size: ");
   scanf("%d", &startingAmount);

   return startingAmount;
}
```

I have also tried putting the if statement within the function getInitialSize itself, but that also was not a solution.

Comment: When you call `getInitialSize()` in the `if` block, you don't assign its return value to `initialSize`. Hence "the initial negative value gets assigned to the variable to do the computations, resulting in an incorrect output."

Comment: near the bottom of the loop is the statement: `getInitialSize();`  However, the returned value is NOT being assigned to the variable: `int initialSize`   Also, since the allowed value must be positive ( >0 ) strongly suggest using `unsigned int` rather than `int` for the variable type and `scanf("%u", &startingAmount);`  Notice the `%u`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`  and  a prototype (before `main()`) of `int getInitialSize( void );`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend also adding a test to be sure that the user actually entered a valid number *at all*, because if they entered garbage, then the `startingAmount` variable won't have a reasonable value at all.

```
int getInitialSize() {

   int startingAmount;

   do
   {
     printf("Enter initial size: ");
   } while (scanf("%d", &startingAmount) < 1  || startingAmount < 0);

   return startingAmount;
}
```

Now it loops asking the user for input *either* if they didn't type a valid number *or* the number they entered is not to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

So, on first inspection, you have initialized the variable `initialSize`, but when you want to recompute it, you are missing an assignment. Since you want to repeat the query for the value until it is non-negative, you should use a loop.

```
   int initialSize = getInitialSize();

   while (initialSize < 0) {
      printf("Initial size must be greater than or equal to 0");
      initialSize = getInitialSize();
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getInitialSize();
int main(){
int initialSize = getInitialSize();

if (initialSize < 0) {
printf("Iinitial size must be greater than or equal to 0");
getInitialSize();
}
return 0;
}
int getInitialSize() {
int startingAmount;
printf("Enter initial size: ");
do{
scanf("%d", &startingAmount);
}while(startingAmount<0);
return startingAmount;
}
```

Here use loop like that. Ofc with this you don't need to check it in main.